# Youtube API search auto-complete in android

Tags: android, json, youtube, android-youtube-api

I'm using Youtube API, I'd like to have a search auto-complete feature, just like int the site, when i type into the search input box, nothing data is getting. when i post this link into the webbrowser then .txt file has been downloaded that has json suggest.
so, tell me how can get youtube api suggestion in json format?

Comment: http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=youtube&ds=yt&q=tum+mile

Comment: i'm using this url in android.

Comment: So what exactly is the part you're having difficulty with? The txt file contains JSONP, which is easy enough to parse. To get plain JSON, swap out the `client=youtube` query parameter for `client=firefox`. I.e. http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=tum+mile

Comment: yes, it is easy to parse  but question is json data not get, .txt file get and extract data from .txt file.

Comment: If you look at the actual body of the response, you'll see that it's a plain JSON array. Run the request through something like https://www.hurl.it/ and look at the body data. The only reason you're getting a file named `f.txt` is because of the `Content-Disposition` header in the response, which makes a suggestion to your browser to save the response data into a file with the given name. You shouldn't care about that though, as it doesn't change the fact that the response data is just JSON, which you can easily consume for use within your app.